# bash empty string/command

Tags: linux, string, bash

I found some strange thing in bash and I can't understand how it works.

```
[test ~]$ a=""
[test ~]$ $a && echo 1
1

[test ~]$ $a
[test ~]$ echo $?
0
```

Why does $a (which is empty) return 0? Is it somehow transformed to empty command?
If I add quotes or write empty string before `&&`, it will return error. While empty command returns 0.

```
[test ~]$ "$a" && echo 1
-bash: : command not found

[test ~]$ "" && echo 1
-bash: : command not found

[test ~]$ `` && echo 1
1
```

So, what is happening when I type $a?

Comment: That might be a bug in `bash`'s parser. `"$a" && echo 1` produces an error, since the empty string is not a valid command. `&& echo 1` produces a syntax error. `$a && echo 1` should produce the same syntax error, but seems to behave the same as `: && echo 1.

Comment: Actually, I guess the parser recognizes two commands separated by `&&` before `$a` evaluates to nothing, at which point it is treated as an empty command rather than a parse error.

Comment: ...aside: Variables should never be used to store commands in the first place. See BashFAQ #50, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: And the same thing happens with semicolon: `$a; echo hello` and with subshells `( $a )` and with groups `{ $a; }`.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to confuse `bash` with some other programming language. Variables get replaced, then what is left gets executed.

```
"$a"
```

This is the content of `a`, between quotation marks. `a` is empty, so this is equivalent to:

```
""
```

That is not a command. "Command not found." As there was an error, the execution was not successful (shell return code is not 0), so the second half of the command -- `&& echo 1` -- does not get executed.

Backticks...

```
``
```

...execute whatever is between them, with the output of that command replacing the whole construct. (There is also `$()` which does the same, and is less prone to being overlooked in a script.) So...

```
`echo "foo"`
```

...would evaluate to...

```
foo
```

...which would then be executed. So your...

```
``
```

...evaluates to...

```
 <empty>
```

...which is then "executed successfully" (since there is no error).

If you want to **test** the contents of `a`, and execute `echo 1` only if `a` is not empty, you should use the `test` command:

```
test -n "$a" && echo 1
```

There is a convenient alias for `test`, which is `[`, which also conveniently ignores a trailing `]`...

```
[ -n "$a" ] && echo 1
```

...and a bash-ism `[[` that "knows" about variable replacement and thus does not need quotation marks to avoid complaining about a missing argument if `$a` does indeed evaluate to empty...

```
[[ -n $a ]] && echo 1
```

...or, of course, the more verbose...

```
if [[ -n $a ]]
then
    echo 1
fi
```

---

Ah. Missed the core part of the question:

```
$a && echo 1
```

This is two statements, separated by `&&`. The second statement only gets executed if the first one executes OK. The bash takes the line apart and executes the first statement:

```
$a
```

This is...

```
<empty>
```

...which is "successful", so the second statement gets executed. Opposed to that...

```
&& echo 1
```

...is a syntax error because *there is no first statement*. ;-) (Tricky, I know, but that's the way this cookie crumbles.)

Comment: You haven't explained, though, why `$a && echo 1` produces the result it does.

Comment: @chepner: Did so just as you commented. ;-)

Comment: Also, I mixed up parsing with evaluation. `$a && echo 1` does not undergo parameter expansion, rather the parser identifies two commands `$a` and `echo 1`, each of which is evaluated separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=""
```

or

```
a="                       " #a long empty string
```

then

```
$> $a
```

will return 0

```
$> $noExistVar
```

will also return 0.

They get "executed", in fact, nothing gets executed. same as you press enter or pressing 10 spaces then enter, you get return code 0 too.

```
$>       && echo 1
```

this will fail, because bash will try to execute the first part, in this case it is missing.

```
$> $notExistVar && echo 1
```

Here it works, I **guess** bash found the first part the `$whatever`, therefore no syntax error. Then "execute" it, well nothing to execute, return 0, (same as pressing enter after prompt), then check, if first part returned 0, exec the cmd after `&&`.

I said **guess** because I didn't check bash's source codes. Please correct me if it is wrong.

the `$> "  " && echo 1` case, I think it is clear, don't need to explain.